# Asynctask, dimensions expected after this token

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Im following the android docs on asynctask, trying to get an asynctask going that can perform actions on wifi in background, the issue im running into is at Asynctask in the code below, void and boolean or whatever i put there keep showing up as errors with the message "Dimensions expected after token". I dont know what this is referring to, everything above this section looks fine and works fine, couldnt find much on google either.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
.......

class wifilistener extends AsyncTask<WifiManager,void,boolean> //trouble spot {

            protected void onPreExecute(){
                //show info on UI thread
            }



            protected boolean doInBackground(WifiManager...wifi1) {
                //do stuff
                }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(){

            }

                protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {

                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try Void and Boolean; you have to use Object instead of primitive type for Asynctask. So, use uppercase V and B, and that should work.

Comment: Capital fix works on both void and boolean. Changed to Void and Boolean now, its good to go....

Comment: Oop, I skipped over the void. But yes, you have to use Object instead of primitive type for Asynctask :)